# Smallest Number in a List - Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write a function that takes a list input and returns the index of the smallest number in that list. 
For example,

```
minPos( [5,4,3,2,1] ) → 4
```

When I run my function, I get a List Index error, can someone please help? Thanks. I cannot use the built in function min().

```
def MinPos(L):
     Subscript = 0
     Hydrogen = 1
     SmallestNumber = L[Subscript]

    while L[Subscript] < len(L):
          while  L[Subscript] < L[Subscript + Hydrogen]:
                Subscript += 1
                return SmallestNumber

          while L[Subscript] > L[Subscript + Hydrogen]:
                Subscript += 1

    return SmallestNumber


def main():
    print MinPos( [-5,-4] )
```

Comment: Can you please reindent the code? also the function name should be 'min_pos', while all the variables should be in lower case, this is a custom in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
>>> def min_pos(L):
...    min = None
...    for i,v in enumerate(L):
...        if min is None or min[1] > v:
...            min = (i,v)
...    return min[0] if min else None


>>> min_pos([1,3,4,5])
0

>>> min_pos([1,3,4,0,5])
3
```

Edit: Return None if empty list

Comment: breaks on empty list (`None[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to find the minimum value, you simply feed that value to the index() function to get the index of this value in the list. I.e,

```
>>> n = ([5,4,3,2,1])
>>> n.index(min(n))
4
```

This will return the index of the minimum value in the list. Note that if there are several minima it will return the first.

Comment: OP says cant use built in min function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use of `for ...` and `enumarate()`:

```
data = [6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5]

try:
    index, minimum = 0, data[0]
    for i, value in enumerate(data):
        if value < minimum:
            index, minimum = i, value
except IndexError:
    index = None
print index
# Out[49]: 2
```

*EDIT* added guard against empty `data`